# How to apply where condition in each inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to apply conditions on each inner join like below

```
 select * 
 from table1 table 
 inner join table2 t on t.column= table.column where condition
 inner join table3 tb on tb.column = table.column where condition
```

But error is thrown on second where condition

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'.

Very new to joins in SQL Server. Any help please?

Comment: after all joins put where condition not after every join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `WHERE` clauses at the end of the statement, but you can do this in an inner join like this:

```
select * from table1 table 
 inner join table2 t on t.column= table.column 
      and t.someColumn = 'SomeValue' --Here you can join on a condition
 inner join table3 tb on tb.column = t.column 
 where <condition>


--Or...

select * from table1 table 
 inner join table2 t on t.column= table.column 
 inner join table3 tb on tb.column = t.column 
where
 t.column = 'blah'
 and tb.column = 'blah2'
```

Answer (score 4):

With an `inner join` all the conditions apply to the complete recordset. So you can just put them all in the `where` clause

```
select * 
from table1 table 
inner join table2 t on t.column= table.column
inner join table3 tb on tb.column = table.column 
where condition1 and condition2
```

But for instance when using a `left join` the conditions only apply to the join itself. So you can use the `on` clause like this

```
select *
from table1 table 
left join table2 t on t.column = table.column AND condition1
left join table3 tb on tb.column = table.column AND condition2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to keep your main query clean, you can use a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to logically filter your table, away from your main query:

```
;with Employees as
(
    select * from People where PersonType = 'Employee'
)
select * from ParkingSpots ps
join Employees e on ps.PersonID = e.PersonID
```